# ffmpeg can't change number of B-frames

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, h.264

When streaming from a source I keep receiving frames following the same pattern:
`I-frame P-frame I-frame P-frame I-frame P-frame ...`.
I tried many options and read as many questions here as I found, but I can't find a way to increse the number of P-frame or at least enable B-frames.

Mainly it seems that I should use:

```
 ffprobe rtsp://localhost/video -g 30 -bf 3 -show_frames -of csv
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Crossposted to https://superuser.com/q/1651968

Answer (score 1):

With the `-bf` option you set the number of B-frames.

But you have to use `ffmpeg` to reencode the input in order to change the GOP structure.

Take for example:

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -g 12 -bf 2 -flags +cgop output.mp4`

The resulting output should have the following GOP structure:

| position |  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| frame | I | B | B | P | B | B | P | B | B | P | B | B | I |

On a shell you can easily output the GOP structure with `ffprobe`.

Analyze 2 seconds of the file:

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -map 0 -c copy -t 2 -f nut pipe: | ffprobe pipe: -show_frames | grep pict_type`

Comment: Without `grep`: `ffprobe -v error -show_entries frame=pict_type -of csv=p=0 -`

Comment: So I have to reencode the video right? Because my goal is to reduce CPU usage.